# How to make branches in a game tree parallel?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, game-tree, istgame

I created the following game tree:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[leqno, oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{istgame}[font=\footnotesize]
        \xtdistance{30mm}{90mm}
        \setxtinfosetstyle{dashed}
        \xtShowEndPoints
        \istroot[right](0)<above>{0}
            \istbA{0.95}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{0.05}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        \xtdistance{30mm}{30mm}
        \istroot[right](1)(0-2)<above>{1.1}
            \istbA{g_1\quad(\beta)}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{f_1\quad(1-\beta)}[above,sloped]{0,0}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(1){\makecell{$\langle\alpha\rangle$}}[below]
        \istroot[right](2)(0-1)<above>{1.1}
            \istbA(2){g_1\quad(\beta)}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{f_1\quad(1-\beta)}[above,sloped]{0,0}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(2){\makecell{$\langle1-\alpha\rangle$}}[below]
        \istroot[right](3)(1-1)<above>{2.2}
            \istbA{g_2\quad(\gamma)}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{f_2\quad(1-\gamma)}[above,sloped]{-1,5}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(3){\makecell{$\langle1\rangle$}}[below]
        \istroot[right](4)(3-1)<above>{1.3}
            \istbA{g_3\quad(\epsilon)}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{f_3\quad(1-\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{4,4}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(4){\makecell{$\langle\delta\rangle$}}[below]
        \istroot[right](5)(2-1)<above>{1.3}
            \istbA(2){g_3\quad(\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{8,8}
            \istbA{f_3\quad(1-\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{4,4}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(5){\makecell{$\langle1-\delta\rangle$}}[below]
        \istroot[right](6)(4-1)<above>{2.4}
            \istbA{g_4\quad(\zeta)}[above,sloped]{8,8}
            \istbA{f_4\quad(1-\zeta)}[above,sloped]{3,9}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(6){\makecell{$\langle1\rangle$}}[below]
        \xtInfosetO(1)(2)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(3)(3)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(4)(5)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(6)(6)(1.2cm)
    \end{istgame}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I want to make every up-going branch be parallel with each other and every down-going branch be parallel with each other as well. (As you can see, right now the down-going lines are not parallel.) Meanwhile, the two 1.1 nodes need to be aligned and the two 1.3 nodes need to be aligned as well. How should I do that? I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not very familiar with this package, but I looked through the documentation and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the angle of the alternative (or arc) `\istbA`; there is only, as you have done, a way to specify the spread of the children.

For diagnostic purposes, I made the following diagram:
[image: original tree, stripped]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{istgame}
        \xtdistance{30mm}{90mm}
        \setxtinfosetstyle{dashed}
        \xtShowEndPoints

        \setistgrowdirection'{east}
        
        \istroot(0)<above>{0}
            \istbA{to:0-1}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{to:0-2}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        
        \xtdistance{30mm}{30mm}
        
        \istroot(1)(0-1)<above>{1}
            \istbA{to:1-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:1-2}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        \xtOwner(1){\makecell{1label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(2)(0-2)<above>{2}
            \istbA{to:2-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA(2){to:2-2}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        \xtOwner(2){\makecell{2label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(3)(1-2)<above>{3}
            \istbA{to:3-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:3-2}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        \xtOwner(3){\makecell{3label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(4)(3-2)<above>{4}
            \istbA{to:4-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:4-2}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        \xtOwner(4){\makecell{4label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(5)(2-2)<above>{5}
            \istbA{to:5-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA(2){to:5-2}[above,sloped]{end}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(5){\makecell{5label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(6)(4-2)<above>{6}
            \istbA{to:6-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:6-2}[above,sloped]{end}
        \endist
        \xtOwner(6){\makecell{6label}}[below]
        
        \xtInfosetO(1)(2)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(3)(3)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(4)(5)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(6)(6)(1.2cm)
    \end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

There is a way to add 'missing' children, using `\istb<missing>` or `\istbm` for short. Unfortunately, it's difficult to tell how the angle of the `\istbA(<level>)` is calculated, so trying to align the bottom row by adding these missing children proved to be too tedious even with this stripped-down model.

Instead, if you are willing to compromise the symmetry, I offer this solution:
[image: alternative tree, stripped]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{istgame}
        \xtdistance{30mm}{60mm}
        \setxtinfosetstyle{dashed}
        \xtShowEndPoints

        \setistgrowdirection'{east}
        
        \istroot(0)<above>{0}
            \istbA{to:0-1}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{to:0-2}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        
        \xtdistance{30mm}{30mm}
        
        \istroot(1)(0-1)<above>{1}
            \istbA{to:1-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:1-2}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(1){\makecell{1label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(2)(0-2)<above>{2}
            \istbA{to:2-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA(2){to:2-2}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(2){\makecell{2label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(3)(1-2)<above>{3}
            \istbA{to:3-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:3-2}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(3){\makecell{3label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(4)(3-2)<above>{4}
            \istbA{to:4-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:4-2}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(4){\makecell{4label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(5)(2-2)<above>{5}
            \istbA{to:5-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA(2){to:5-2}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(5){\makecell{5label}}[below]
        
        \istroot(6)(4-2)<above>{6}
            \istbA{to:6-1}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbA{to:6-2}[above,sloped]{end}
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(6){\makecell{6label}}[below]
        
        \xtInfosetO(1)(2)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(3)(3)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(4)(5)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(6)(6)(1.2cm)
    \end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

Which, when filled in, looks like
[image]

Again, this is less than ideal, but if your goal is parallel at all costs this will do it. I recommend adding `[scale=1.2]` or similar to the `\begin{istgame}` for scaling, but that is personal preference. In the MWE below, you will notice that I removed the `[right]` tags and added `\setistgrowdirection'{east}` instead, which keeps the nodes top-to-bottom arranged in a sensible way in the code, at least in my opinion.

Hopefully this helps a little!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{istgame}
        \xtdistance{30mm}{60mm}
        \setxtinfosetstyle{dashed}
        \xtShowEndPoints

        \setistgrowdirection'{east}
        
        \istroot(0)<above>{0}
            \istbA{0.05}[above,sloped]
            \istbA{0.95}[above,sloped]
        \endist
        
        \xtdistance{30mm}{30mm}
        
        \istroot(1)(0-1)<above>{1.1}
            \istbA{f_1\quad(1-\beta)}[above,sloped]{0,0}
            \istbA{g_1\quad(\beta)}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(1){\makecell{$\langle\alpha\rangle$}}[below]
        
        \istroot(2)(0-2)<above>{1.1}
            \istbA{f_1\quad(1-\beta)}[above,sloped]{0,0}
            \istbA(2){g_1\quad(\beta)}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(2){\makecell{$\langle1-\alpha\rangle$}}[below]
        
        \istroot(3)(1-2)<above>{2.2}
            \istbA{f_2\quad(1-\gamma)}[above,sloped]{-1,5}
            \istbA{g_2\quad(\gamma)}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(3){\makecell{$\langle1\rangle$}}[below]
        
        \istroot(4)(3-2)<above>{1.3}
            \istbA{f_3\quad(1-\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{4,4}
            \istbA{g_3\quad(\epsilon)}[above,sloped]
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(4){\makecell{$\langle\delta\rangle$}}[below]
        
        \istroot(5)(2-2)<above>{1.3}
            \istbA{f_3\quad(1-\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{4,4}
            \istbA(2){g_3\quad(\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{8,8}
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(5){\makecell{$\langle1-\delta\rangle$}}[below]
        
        \istroot(6)(4-2)<above>{2.4}
            \istbA{f_4\quad(1-\zeta)}[above,sloped]{3,9}
            \istbA{g_4\quad(\zeta)}[above,sloped]{8,8}
            \istbm
        \endist
        \xtOwner(6){\makecell{$\langle1\rangle$}}[below]
        
        \xtInfosetO(1)(2)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(3)(3)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(4)(5)(1.2cm)
        \xtInfosetO(6)(6)(1.2cm)
    \end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would like to use `\istb` instead of using `\istbA`.

You may want to replace `\istbA(2)` with

`\istbA(2)<grow=-27,level distance=67mm>`

or simply to use

`\istb<grow=-27,level distance=67mm>`.

This change will give the (approximate) result you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno, oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{istgame}[font=\footnotesize]
    %%% some calculation:
    \pgfmathparse{90-atan(30/15)}  
        \node(0,0)[draw,yshift=10mm]{\pgfmathresult};
    \pgfmathparse{sqrt(30^2+15^2)} 
        \node(0,0)[draw,yshift=15mm]{\pgfmathresult};
    %%% tree direction
    \setistgrowdirection{east}     %%% instead of using [right] in \istroot
    %\setistgrowdirection'{east}   %%% (swap version) looks more convenient

    %%% \istb (instead of \istbA)
    \xtdistance{30mm}{90mm}
    \setxtinfosetstyle{dashed}
    \xtShowEndPoints
    \istroot(0)<above>{0}
        \istb{0.95}[above,sloped]
        \istb{0.05}[above,sloped]
    \endist
    \xtdistance{30mm}{30mm}
    \istroot(1)(0-2)<above>{1.1}
        \istb{g_1\quad(\beta)}[above,sloped]
        \istb{f_1\quad(1-\beta)}[above,sloped]{0,0}
    \endist
    \xtOwner(1){\makecell{$\langle\alpha\rangle$}}[below]
    \istroot(2)(0-1)<above>{1.1}
        \istb<grow=-27,level distance=67mm>[blue,thick]  %%% CHANGED
             {g_1\quad(\beta)}[above,sloped]
        \istb{f_1\quad(1-\beta)}[above,sloped]{0,0}
    \endist
    \xtOwner(2){\makecell{$\langle1-\alpha\rangle$}}[below]
    \istroot(3)(1-1)<above>{2.2}
        \istb{g_2\quad(\gamma)}[above,sloped]
        \istb{f_2\quad(1-\gamma)}[above,sloped]{-1,5}
    \endist
    \xtOwner(3){\makecell{$\langle1\rangle$}}[below]
    \istroot(4)(3-1)<above>{1.3}
        \istb{g_3\quad(\epsilon)}[above,sloped]
        \istb{f_3\quad(1-\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{4,4}
    \endist
    \xtOwner(4){\makecell{$\langle\delta\rangle$}}[below]
    \istroot(5)(2-1)<above>{1.3}
        \istb<grow=-27,level distance=67mm>[blue,thick]  %%% CHANGED
             {g_3\quad(\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{8,8}
        \istb{f_3\quad(1-\epsilon)}[above,sloped]{4,4}
    \endist
    \xtOwner(5){\makecell{$\langle1-\delta\rangle$}}[below]
    \istroot(6)(4-1)<above>{2.4}
        \istb{g_4\quad(\zeta)}[above,sloped]{8,8}
        \istb{f_4\quad(1-\zeta)}[above,sloped]{3,9}
    \endist
    \xtOwner(6){\makecell{$\langle1\rangle$}}[below]
    \xtInfosetO(1)(2)(1.2cm)
    \xtInfosetO(3)(3)(1.2cm)
    \xtInfosetO(4)(5)(1.2cm)
    \xtInfosetO(6)(6)(1.2cm)
\end{istgame}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```